# Symfony Easyadmin - How to add a custom action near "btn action-new"?

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I would like to add a custom action near " btn action-new" in list page.
I try:

```
entities:
    Pratiquant:
        class: AppBundle/Entity/Pratiquant
        actions:
            - {name: 'fichePresence',  type: 'method', action: 'fichePresence', label: 'fiche de presence' }
```

I don't need this:

```
entities:
    Pratiquant:
        class: AppBundle/Entity/Pratiquant
        list: 
            actions:
                - {name: 'fichePresence',  type: 'method', action: 'fichePresence', label: 'fiche de presence' }
```

Hope someone understand me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration is correct ... but it doesn't do what you want to achieve. Right now, all the actions configured for the `list` view are considered actions for the items displayed in the listing. There is no built-in way to define "global actions" for `list` view.

In any case, you can do what you want by overriding a small fragment of the `list` template. To do so, create the following Twig template (it's very important to store it in that exact location):

```
{# app/Resources/views/easy_admin/Pratiquant/list.html.twig #}
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/list.html.twig' %}

{% block view_actions %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <a href="{{ path('easyadmin', { view: 'fichePresence' }) }}">Fiche de presence</a>
{% endblock %}
```

This will execute the `fichePresenceAction()` method of your custom `AdminController`.

Comment: Perfect! I've just modified the path and add the created template to Pratiquant template config.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool. But there is no need to define the custom template in the config (unless there is a bug in the bundle). Having the template at that location would be enough for the bundle to autodiscover it.

Comment: Currently there is no `view_actions` block, but the `global_actions` instead.

Answer (score 3):

With EasyAdmin 3 :

```
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{
    $fichePresence = Action::new('fichePresence', 'fiche de presence', 'fa fa-download')
        ->linkToCrudAction('fichePresenceAction')
        ->createAsGlobalAction();

    return $actions
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $fichePresence);
}
```

[See documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/actions.html#adding-custom-actions)